# Symbol's function definition is void on built-in variables?

Tags: functions, variables, symbols

For some reason I am getting errors for built-in variables that are available in the documentation.

For instance, evaluating in the `scratch` buffer the following all return:

`Symbol's function definition is void:`

- `emacs-major-version`
- `emacs-minor-version`
- `display-time-24hr-format`

This is so weird because there is documentation for all of these, they show up in auto-complete and I see other users using them.

I can not use these in my `.emacs` or anywhere else.  Interestingly however, I can set some of them using `customize`.  For instance:

`(display-time-24hr-format t)` does work in the customize block

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You get `Symbol's function definition is void` because those are variables, not functions.

Below will work:

```
M-: emacs-major-version
```

Below will not work:

```
M-: (emacs-major-version)
```

Comment: Ah yes, silly mistake.  However, can you help me with `(display-time-24-hr-format t)` which I am pretty sure is a function?

Comment: @Startec Nope, That's a variable too. Looks like you are partially evaluating the auto-generated customize forms.. `(setq display-time-2hr-format t)` will work. If something shows up in `C-h v`, that's a variable. If something shows up in `C-h f`, that's a function.

Comment: You should be evaluating the whole `(customize-set-variables ..)` form, not just elements of array in it.

Comment: I am still learning lisp and wanted to write it myself.  I thought I could just use that because it looked like `(blink-cursor-mode t)`  These slight differences are rough.

Comment: @Startec `blink-cursor-mode` is both a function and a variable, the `customize-set-variables` form refers to the variable.

Comment: In the call to the function `customize-set-variables` the likes of `(display-time-24hr-format t)` are *data* (in this case a list which associates the value `t` with the variable `display-time-24hr-format`; data that will be used by the function to assign that value to that variable. Because lisp function calls are also written in list format, a list which is completely out of context could be either data or a function call.